# OpenThread and closing multiple thread handles

Tags: c++, winapi, handle

I have a thread handle A which I got using `OpenThread`.
Later in my program I need to use `OpenThread` again on the same thread and to get its handle again, let's call it handle B.
Looking at the "watch" window, I can see that A != B.
When the thread dies I want to close its handle.
Would it be enough to close just handle A or just handle B? or do I need to close all the handles?
Can I ask `OpenThread` to give me a handle that I already got from it before, or will it always give me new handles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to close every handle. There is no way to get an existing handle from OpenThread, it will always create a new handle.

However, your problem description suggests that there is a deeper architectural problem here. **Why** do you want to do this?

Comment: Yes, I know I shouldn't do it, but I was curious. :)